# Know if a user is already registered with Reactjs & firebase-google auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-authentication

I am creating a web app with Reactjs and firebase and I am facing a small problem.
I have a registration / login system thanks to firebase and gmail accounts.
When a user registers, in addition to the classic firebase function, I call a function to record user information in my database.

The problem I encounter is the following:
if a user who is already registered through his google account, that he filled things in the application and that it was registered in base, if the user tries to register again (because he has forgot that it was already registered), all information about it is removed from the database.
For example, here is the structure of my base:

```
users
- user-1
--- E-mail
--- username
--- data
----- sub-data
- user-2
--- E-mail
--- username
--- data
----- sub-data
```

If user 1 tries to sign up again, here is the new base:

```
users
- user-1
--- E-mail
--- username
--- data
----- sub-data
- user-2
--- E-mail
--- username
--- data
----- sub-data
```

So, this is my code for the signup part :

```
auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider)
.then((result) => {
db.doCreateUser(result.user.uid, result.user.displayName,
result.user.email);
});
```

and the doCreateUser function :

```
doCreateUser = (id, username, email) =>
db.ref(`users/${id}`).set({
username: username,
email: email,
});
```

Is it possible to know if a user is already registered on this Google Account? If so, can you give me some ideas to do it?

I tried to recover an error by doing this:

```
authen.signInWithPopup (provider) .catch (function (error) {
console.log (error);
});
```

but the console is empty

If not, how not to replace the data (either by direct connection with rather than by re-registering it or re-recording it while keeping the data in "data" and sub-data ")?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I finally found thanks to result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser, I had already tried before but not as obviously